# Add a subdirectory to a python namespace

Tags: python

I would like to be able to import a python module which is actually located in a subdirectory of another module.

I am developing a framework with plug-ins.
Since I'm expecting to have a few thousands (there's currently >250 already) and I don't want one big directory containing >1000 files I have them ordered in directories like this, where they are grouped by the first letter of their name:

```
framework\
    __init__.py
    framework.py
    tools.py
    plugins\
        __init__.py
        a\
            __init__.py
            atlas.py
            ...
        b\
            __init__.py
            binary.py
            ...
        c\
            __init__.py
            cmake.py
        ...
```

Since I would not like to impose a burden on developers of other plugins, or people not needing as many as I have, I would like to put each plugin in the 'framework.plugins' namespace.
This way someone adding a bunch of private plugins can just do so by adding them in the folder framework.plugins and there provide a `__init__.py` file containing:

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

however, currently this setup is forcing them to also use the a-z subdirectories.
Sometimes a plugin is extending another plugin, so now  I have a

```
from framework.plugins.a import atlas
```

and I would like to have

```
from framework.pugins import atlas
```

Is there any way to declare a namespace where the full name space name actually doesn't map to a folder structure?

I am aware of the pkg_resources package, but this is only available via setuptools, and I'd rather not have an extra dependency.

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)
```

The solution should work in python 2.4-2.7.3

update:
Combining the provided answers I tried to get a list of all plugins imported in the `__init__.py` from plugins. However, this fails due to dependencies. Since a plugin in the 'c' folder tries to import a plugin starting with 't', and this one has not been added yet.

```
plugins = [ x[0].find_module(x[1]).load_module(x[1]) for x in pkgutil.walk_packages([ os.path.join(framework.plugins.__path__[0], chr(y)) for y in xrange(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1) ],'framework.plugins.' ) ]
```

I'm not sure If I'm on the right track here, or just overcomplicating things and better write my own PEP302 importer. However, I can't seem to find any decent examples of how these should work.

Update:
I tried to follow the suggesting of wrapping the `__getattr__` function in my `__init__.py`, but this seems to no avail.

```
import pkgutil
import os
import sys
plugins = [x[1] for x in pkgutil.walk_packages([ os.path.join(__path__[0], chr(y)) for y in xrange(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1) ] )]
import types
class MyWrapper(types.ModuleType):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
            self.wrapped = wrapped

    def __getattr__(self, name):
           if name in plugins:
                   askedattr =  name[0] + '.' + name
            else:
                    askedattr = name
            attr = getattr(self.wrapped, askedattr)
            return attr


sys.modules[__name__] = MyWrapper(sys.modules[__name__])
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a specific reason for which you'd rather not depend on setuptools? Unless you're in a very specific situation, I honestly think you can expect reasonnably expect users to have `setuptools` / `pip` installed anyway (And `setuptools` itself is widely available and easily installed using the egg.).

Comment: This is a framework for compiling software from source currently counting >16000 lines of code.
We don't assume the user has root privileges and/or can easily install software in any other way. So currently the only real dependency is python> 2.4 < 3.0.

Comment: setuptools/pip will either install to the root installation or to the user's home directory ( or to a virtualenv ).  it's not necessary to have root privileges to install python modules.

Comment: Yes, but if you haven't got setuptools or pip yet, it's not that easy to actually install it. We're going for 1 tarbal, unzipping it, done.
Also, I felt there had to be a really simple way, I found it with manually extending `__path__` now. So really not needed. 
Also, declare_namespace still needed you to leave the directory structure to agree with the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `pkgutil.extend_path` function here, it tries to do the opposite of what you're trying to accomplish:

> This will add to the package’s `__path__` all subdirectories of
>   directories on sys.path named after the package.
>   This is useful if one wants to distribute different parts of a 
>   single logical package as multiple directories.

Just extending `__path__` with the subdirectories in your `framework.plugins.__init__.py` works just fine.

So the solution to this problem is: put this in your `__init__.py`:

```
__path__.extend([os.path.join(__path__[0],chr(y)) for y in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to import your `a`, `b`... modules in `plugins.__init__`, like:

```
from a import atlas
from b import binary
...
```

Comment: I would be adding new plugins all the day, since this framework is under heavy development by a couple of different developers, adding an import every time is just not an option. I'm looking into a clean solution, preferably only 1-2 lines of python.

Comment: And what if, say, you have another `atlas.py` in module `b` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, the a-z directory structure is there to reflect the first letter of the module name, this is to group the files, so I don't end up with 1 directory containing >1000 files.

Comment: Then, what about `pkgutil.extend_path`, as described [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0382/) and [there] (http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html) ?

Comment: As you can see in the answer, I am already using this. This works fine if I want to force everybody to use the a-z directory structure. But I don't mind creating a large namespace, only a large directory. So I would like to group each directory in the framework.plugins  namespace. I'm hopefull that this can be achieved with pkgutil indeed, but can't seem to find a working solution or any examples for that matter.

Comment: why don't you want a directory with > 1000 files ?  any modern filesystem can handle that number fine.

you're also not really safeguarding against any real folder content limits - this assumes there's a relatively even distribution of modules by the first letter - this rarely/never happens.  it's not unlikely that a single folder could have over 1000 modules if you double your current size.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco yeah, you are probably right, 8 years later and we're only up to 1798 plugins. However the distribution is surprisingly  even: https://easybuild.readthedocs.io/en/latest/version-specific/Supported_software.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest lazy-loading the modules by subclassing `types.ModuleType` and converting `modname` to `modname[0] + '.' + modname` on demand; this should be less work than implementing a module loader.

You can look at [apipkg](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/apipkg/1.2) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: How would I then let python know to use this new ModuleType for modules in the framework.plugins directory?

Comment: @JensTimmerman you replace the module in `sys.modules[pkgname]`.  See https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/apipkg/src/tip/apipkg.py#cl-14

Comment: So I had to repeat this for every module again? This will again give me the dependency problem where I have to first resolve the dependencies. I'd rather just tell python to use the new type for each module in this submodule, but assigning to type.ModuleType does not work...

Comment: @JensTimmerman no, just for the module `framework.plugins`; a reference `from framework.plugins modname` is a `getattr` on `sys.modules["framework.plugins"]`.

Comment: Yes, I meant this basically is about same as importing each plugin in the `framework/plugins/__init__.py` ? But doing it lazy.

Comment: @JensTimmerman lazy, but automatically, by writing a `__getattr__` that does the translation.

Comment: I added the code I've written after your suggestion to my question, but can't get it to completely work.
However, I came across a very simple and working solution, so I'll go ahead and accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a particularly fast solution (startup overheads), but what about having plugins.__init__ scrape the filesystem and import each found file into the local namespace?

```
import glob
import sys

thismodule = sys.modules[__name__]

for plugin in glob.glob("?/*"):
    _temp = __import__(plugin.split("/")[0],
                   globals(),
                   locals(),
                   [plugin.split("/")[1]],
                   -1)
   setattr(thismodule, plugin.split("/")[1], getattr(_temp, plugin.split("/")[1]))
```

Comment: Your code got me thinking, and I came up with this: modules = [ x[0].find_module(x[1]).load_module(x[1]) for x in  pkgutil.walk_packages([ os.path.join(framework.plugins.__path__[0],chr(y)) for y in xrange(ord('a'),ord('z')) ],'framework.plugins.' ) ]
But this doesn't work because of dependencies. A plugin in the /c/ directory already tries to import one in the /t/ directory, which is not available yet at that time, since I haven't added it as an attribute yet.

Comment: Interdependence like that could cause you more problems further on - either import directly (from plugins.t import Thing) or rework the interdependencies to something external to the plugins.

Comment: We're currently using the direct import indeed. But I thought it would be relatively easy to just add everything to a namespace, without the directory structure interfering. I just can't seem to find the easiest way.